# What is the appropriate version of framework for a project running on MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have windows 2008 R2 sp1 server,i want to prepare hosting for project runs on MVC 6 which framework should i i install on server  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASP.NET MVC 6** has been rebranded as **ASP.NET Core MVC** - so if you want to run this, you need to install **.NET Core Runtime** on your server.

The newest released version is .NET Core v2.2 which you can get from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Also, to develop for .NET Core, you'll need the .NET Core v2.2 SDK for your dev machine (which you can download from the same URL).